# Path delimiter in windows and linux for java code

Tags: java, windows, filepath

In my java code, I have some hard coded paths which I have written as

```
String workingPath = initPath + "\\" + tmpPath;
```

the `initPath` and `tmpPath` are obtained by  `File.getParent()`. Now, that works on windows and if I move my code to linux, the `\\` will be problematic since the other two are determined by system methods. The results is something like this

```
/home/mahmood/project/alpha\temp1
```

How can I fix that? I don't want to put `/` in my code for linux systems.

Comment: You can use `/` on both Windows and Linux, another option is to use `File(File, String)` to build your paths.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Your comment is a good solution, it should be an answer post.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a variable you can use: [`File.separator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator)

> The system-dependent default name-separator character, represented as a string for convenience. This field is initialized to contain the first character of the value of the system property file.separator. On UNIX systems the value of this field is '/'; on Microsoft Windows systems it is '\'.

```
String workingPath = initPath + File.separator + tmpPath;
```

Answer (score 4):

The File class has a constructor that accepts a parent directory. If you use this, you don't need to manually concatenate paths.

```
final File parent = new File("/home/mahmood/project/alpha");
final File tmp = new File(parent, "temp1");
```