# How to change the path so that it works with both Windows and Linux in java?

Tags: java, linux, windows

I have a Java Project which currently supports Windows i.e I have hardcoded the windows C drive path at various places like `property file , hibernate config file ,log4J file , jsp file (For eg : "C:/software/server/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/xxx/file.log")`. Now I want to make the same code working on linux but the problem is file path which is hard-coded everywhere . How do I make the same code work for both Windows and Linux . What do I need to change in file path to make it work .

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked many times before:

### [Path delimiter in windows and linux for java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44250017/path-delimiter-in-windows-and-linux-for-java-code)

There is a variable you can use: File.separator

The system-dependent default name-separator character, represented as a string for convenience. This field is initialized to contain the first character of the value of the system property file.separator. On UNIX systems the value of this field is '/'; on Microsoft Windows systems it is '\'.

```
String workingPath = initPath + File.separator + tmpPath;
```

Comment: I don't want to do anything in the code , I just want to make the changes in hard-coded files in such a way that the code needs to be changed minimum.