# Adding a single forward slash or double backward slash to directory path in java

Tags: java, swing, filepath, jfilechooser

I am using JFileChooser to get a directory path in a project of mine. It is working perfectly, but there is a little problem. Suppose this is the directory structure:

```
->Home
  ->Documents
    ->Java
```

This is the code:

```
JFileChooser fileChooser=new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        int userSelection=fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);
        if(userSelection==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            try{File fileTosave=fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                File newFile=new File(fileTosave.getAbsolutePath()+"satish.txt");
                System.out.println(newFile);
                this.dispose();}
            catch(Exception e){}
        }
```

If currently i am inside the java folder, it gives me the path `Home/Documents/Java`(or Home:\Documents\Java) in windows. What I want is that it should return the path which includes single forward slash or double forward slash (according to plaform) such that it looks like `Home/Documents/Java/`. I want to do this because later I have to append a file name to this path such that file path becomes `Home/Documents/java/file.txt`.

Any Idea on how to do this?

I don't want to add slashes manually because then I would also have to keep the platform in mind.

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Path delimiter in windows and linux for java code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44250017/path-delimiter-in-windows-and-linux-for-java-code)

Comment: Why there is a downvote? Didn't get that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `java.io.File.pathSeparator`

```
/**
     * The system-dependent path-separator character, represented as a string
     * for convenience.  This string contains a single character, namely
     * <code>{@link #pathSeparatorChar}</code>.
     */
    public static final String pathSeparator = "" + pathSeparatorChar;
```

Your code should look like

```
JFileChooser fileChooser=new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        int userSelection=fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);
        if(userSelection==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
            try{File fileTosave=fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                File newFile=new File(fileTosave.getParent() + File.separator +"satish.txt");
                System.out.println(newFile);
                this.dispose();}
            catch(Exception e){}
        }
```

Comment: Would it work both on windows and Unix well?

Comment: let me know if it works

Comment: I don't have access to windows but it is working indeed on Ubuntu

Comment: `File newFile = new File(fileToSave, "satish.txt");` would produce a correct file path/name for any platform.

Answer (score 0):

Java doesn't provide a method or strategy to convert file paths as Strings to the format for different OS's out of the box. You would need to either write your own method to do this or take advantage of a library that has already solved this for you.

For example, you can use [Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) to solve this, using the method:

```
FilenameUtils.separatorsToSystem(String path)
```